# How can I print two character together with a space between them?

Tags: java

```java
package day1.examples;
import java.util.*;

public class AdvancedInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char a,b;
        System.out.println("Enter Your First Name");
        a = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter Your Last Name");
        b = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Your Full name is:");
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a space between them: `a + " " + b`.

Comment: Write this: System.out.println(a + " " + b);

Comment: Note that if your first name contains two (or more) words, the "last name" input will use the second word of the first name. You may wish to consider using `nextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Would this solve the problem?

```
System.out.println("Your Full name is:");
System.out.println(a+" "+b);
```